# Can't enable Hyper-V on Windows 10 due to Japanese language

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Every time I would try to enable Hyper-V, it fails with this error in CBS.log :

```
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Info                  CBS    Exec: Resolving Package: HyperV-UX-PowerShell-Module-HyperV-WOW64-servercommon-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ja-JP~10.0.17763.1, Update: acc2e8a20c76ffe3547579459bc35e3a, PinDeployment: amd64_hyperv-ux-powershel..oyment-languagepack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_ja-jp_759d6514b48b8eca
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Info                  CBS    Exec: 84 deployments need bulk staging
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Error                 CSI    000067a7@2019/11/19:11:34:20.604 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\csd_locking.cpp(95): Error STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING originated in function CCSDirectTransaction::LockComponent expression: (null)[gle=0x80004005]
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Error                 CSI    000067a8 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING #50936360# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 0 of 1 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd015000c]
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Error                 CSI    000067a9 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING) #50936202# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_PinDeployment(Flags = 0, a = HyperV-UX-PowerShell-Module-HyperV-vm-Deployment-LanguagePack, version 10.0.17763.1, arch amd64, culture [l:5]'ja-JP', nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, cb = (null), s = (null), rid = 'HyperV-UX-PowerShell-Module-HyperV-vm-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ja-JP~10.0.17763.1.882ec3c0a4ad38131b14954a45d63426', rah = (null), manpath = (null), catpat[gle=0x80073701]
2019-11-19 12:34:20, Error                 CSI    h = (null), ed = 0, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073701]
```

---

I'd guess it's the Japanese language installed on my system that produces this error... but I can't uninstall it. Every time I run `lpksetup /u` and try to disinstall Japanese, it ends up with a "Failed to Uninstall". Again my CBS.log looks like this :

```
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Info                  CSI    e35}]) ref: ( flgs: 00000000 guid: {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} name: [l:79]'Package_2_for_KB4486167~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2752.4486167-538_neutral' ncdata: [l:0]'')
  (1684)  MarkUnstaged: flags: 0 tlc: [018e321f53db726f5b2fb527205ef28b, version 4.0.15744.161, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}]) ref: ( flgs: 00000000 guid: {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} name: [l:79]'Package_2_for_KB4486167~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2752.4486167-538_neutral' ncdata: [l:0]'')
  (1685)  Unpin: flags: 0 tlc: [018e321f53db726f5b2fb527205ef28b, version 4.0.15744.161, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}]) ref: ( flgs: 00000000 guid: {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} name: [l:79]'Package_2_for_KB4486167~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2752.4486167-538_neutral' ncdata: [l:0]'')
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b1 (F) The TLC was not marked by this installer[gle=0x80004005]
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b2@2019/11/19:11:39:07.726 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\csd_pin.cpp(624): Error STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND originated in function CCSDirectTransaction::MarkTlcUnstaged expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b3 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND #51154315# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 1 of 1686 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd0150004]
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b4 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND) #51154111# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x800736b3]
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b5 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND) #51154109# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_Commit(Flags = 102, pSink = NULL, disp = 0)[gle=0x800736b3]
2019-11-19 12:39:07, Error                 CSI    000067b6 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND) #51154108# 41041 us from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction_ICSITransaction::Commit(flags = 0x00000066, pSink = NULL, disp = 0)
[gle=0x800736b3]
```

---

I tried many, **many** things to get it done but nothing worked :

- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- sfc /scannow
- Deleting registry key for the language
- Reinstalling Japanese
- Deleting packages one by one (by the way some of them tells me "Access Refused", while others tell me "Assembly not found")

---

PS: My computer is compatible with Hyper-V. Virtualization is enabled.

Comment: Are you trying these from an elevated/admin powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 0x80073701 is `ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING`.
It means that some system files are missing, causing Windows changes to fail.

Perhaps the best way to return these missing files is to effect an
In-place Upgrade, upgrading Windows to itself, using the latest Windows version
in an offline installation.

For details see the article
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: This worked, I can't give a +1 but I wish I could. For the instance, I found out I had a blocked windows update. Doing the In-place Upgrade worked like a charm.